# css line-height not working on mobile device

Tags: ios, css, mobile, vertical-alignment

I have tried to align some items vertical middle using line-height in my hyprid app (ionic)

how i basically did:

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 35px;
  }

.item {
    background: lightgreen;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
  }

.item span {
    line-height:35px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item">
     <span class="icon-check"></span>
     <span>818</span>
   </div>   
</div>
```

What does not work:

In chrome developer mode everything works great: the text is perfect aligned center to the green container..

..but when i render the app on my device (iphone4s ios8.4.1 app: ionic view) the text is no longer vertical centered:

[image]

ex.: if you have a look at the "2" beside the eye-icon u can see that the "2" is not exactly vertical

my Question:
why is there a different between text-displaying in desktop browser and mobile app?
can i fix this?

Thanks

PS: also tryed to center vertical with flex and table-cell but both mothods get the same little different between desktop and mobile

Edit: I aligned the intems again using translate(-50%) and line-height: 1; here is my result:

[image]

after I changed font-family:

[image]

therefore the font-family is responsible for the render issue.
Do I have to choose an other font or is there a way to fix this with the give font ? (on desktop version that doesn't occur ..everything looks great)

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with you, and found it is font's problem...It's so weird, can't understand. It works perfect on any device except IOS chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding in text-align="center" in your div tag like this.

```
<div text-align="center">
```

That should keep the image and the text lined up.
Or you can use this in your CSS.

```
span {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried both but as it turned out the font is responsible for it. But interesting method with the `text-align="center"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `height` on your parent element, instead of using line-height

(i.e) make the button get a specific height instead of using line-height directly on the element.

```css
/*height can make the gap we need, instead of using line-height for iOS scenarios, as an alternative*/

.button {
  width: auto;
  height: 2em;
}

.label {
  /*line-height: 2em; - The line-height property specifies the height of a line.*/
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <spam class="label"> my button </spam>
</button>
```